# How to change <input type="text"> to <tr> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to update a row using jQuery Ajax.

When i click on `Edit` button it changes `<tr>` to `<input type='text'>`, I have added `.Change` method and it successfully fires but i want to change it back to `<tr>` when `change` event is fired.

Kindly check it and guide me how to change it back to `<tr>` whenever user updates a row.

Thanks

```js
 var editing = false;
 $(document).on("click", ".updateUser", function() {

   if (!editing) {
     editing = true;
     $(this).closest('tr').find('.edited').each(function() {
       var html = $(this).html();
       var input = $('<input type="text" />');
       input.val(html);
       $(this).html(input);

     });
   }

 }).change(function() {

   editing = false;
   alert("change Event");

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class=" table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id edited">ID</td>
      <td class="id edited">Username</td>
      <td class="id edited">Password</td>
      <td class="id edited">Role</td>

      <td>
        <button type="button" class="updateUser btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-userId="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          EDIT BUTTON
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- ROW 2 -->

    <tr>
      <td class="id edited">ID</td>
      <td class="id edited">UsernameText</td>
      <td class="id edited">PasswordText</td>
      <td class="id edited">RoleText</td>

      <td>
        <button type="button" class="updateUser btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-userId="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          EDIT BUTTON
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `button` has not change event.

Comment: Yes, i want to add functionality on whenever user enters anything on input field..In the above example, if you enter anything on `input fields` an alert will be displayed

Comment: Are you getting the alert?

Comment: Yes, In the above example If you type anything on input fields an alert will be displayed when you click outside

Comment: JQuery change text to input is that what you mean

Comment: First jQuery changes `<tr>` to `input text field` - Works fine - 
Now when user enters a value in that text field, i want it to revert back to `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is the reverse of what you already have done:

```
var editing = false;
$(document)
  .on(
     "click", 
     ".updateUser", 
     function(){
        if(!editing){
           editing = true;
           $(this)
              .closest('tr')
              .find('.edited')
              .each(
                 function() {
                    var html = $(this).html(),
                        input = $('<input type="text" />');
                    input.val(html);
                    $(this).html(input);
                 }
              );
        }

}).change(
    function(e){
       if(editing){
          editing = false;
          $(e.target)
             .closest('tr')
             .find('.edited')
             .each(
                function() {
                   var val = $(this).children('input').val();
                   $(this).html(val);
                }
             );
      }
});
```

JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/sexojuqoxi/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thank you so much !! :) Its working perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your jquery and it's working. I've added change event for `.edited input` and also a little change in `.updateUser` click event.

```js
var editing = false;
$(document).on("click", ".updateUser", function() {
  if (!editing) {
    editing = true;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.edited').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).find('input').length) {
        var html = $(this).text();
        var input = $('<input type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
      }
    });
  }

}).on('change', '.edited input', function() {
  $(this).parent().text(this.value);
  editing = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class=" table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="id edited">ID</td>
      <td class="id edited">Username</td>
      <td class="id edited">Password</td>
      <td class="id edited">Role</td>

      <td>
        <button type="button" class="updateUser btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-userId="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          EDIT BUTTON
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- ROW 2 -->

    <tr>
      <td class="id edited">ID</td>
      <td class="id edited">UsernameText</td>
      <td class="id edited">PasswordText</td>
      <td class="id edited">RoleText</td>

      <td>
        <button type="button" class="updateUser btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-userId="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          EDIT BUTTON
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also a fine solution to inline editing in a table row - [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/furuniyedo/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(document).on("click", ".updateUser", function() {
    var editing = false;

    if (!editing) {
        editing = true;
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.edited').each(function() {
            var html = $(this).html();
            var input = $('<input type="text" />');
            input.val(html);
            $(this).html(input);
        });
        $(this).addClass('save');
        $(this).removeClass('updateUser');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.save', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).closest('td').html($(this).val());
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $(this).removeClass('save');
    $(this).addClass('updateUser');
});
```